# Is there a way to change the state of widget variable located in initState in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

- I have a variable which contains a map of widget in initState.
- One of this widget inside my variable is a gestureDetector who onTap change the value of a variable to change the animation of his child AnimatedAlign.

My problem is that when I active the onTap my animatedAlign stay static.

How should I do to be able to toogle the value of selected ?

```
import 'dart:developer';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  late Map<String, Map<String, List<Widget>>> data;

  bool selected = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState

    data = {
      "Animation and motion widgets": {
        "AnimatedAlign": [
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              setState(() {
                selected = !selected;
              });
              log('$selected inside data');
            },
            child: Center(
              child: Container(
                width: 250.0,
                height: 250.0,
                color: Colors.red,
                child: AnimatedAlign(
                  alignment:
                      selected ? Alignment.topRight : Alignment.bottomLeft,
                  duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
                  curve: Curves.easeInCirc,
                  child: const FlutterLogo(size: 50.0),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      },
      "Animation and motion widgets2": {
        "2widget1": [const Text('2widget1')],
        "2widget2": [const Text('2widget2')]
      }
    };
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Widget catalog'),
      ),
      body: PageView(
        children: _getCategories(),
      ),
    );
  }

  List<Widget> _getCategories() {
    List<Widget> categories = [];

    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      categories.add(
        PageView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          children: getWidgets(i),
        ),
      );
    }
    return categories;
  }

  List<Widget> getWidgets(i) {
    List<Widget> widgetPage = [];
    widgetPage.add(Container(
      color: Colors.red,
      child: Center(
        child: Text(data.keys.toList()[i]),
      ),
    ));
    data[data.keys.toList()[i]]!.forEach((key, value) {
      widgetPage.add(Container(
        color: Colors.blue,
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Center(child: Text(key)),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                child: Column(
                  children: value,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ));
    });
    return widgetPage;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everytime `setState()` is called, `build()` is called in response to it and all the widgets are rebuilt. However, `initState()` is called only when the `StatefulWidget` (`HomeScreen` in your case) is created.

The problem in your code is that `AnimatedAlign` widget is built only once when `initState()` is called. When `setState()` is called, your code reuses the same instance of `AnimatedAlign` as stored in `data` instead of rebuilding it.

For your code to work, you will have to instantiate `data` map object in `build()` instead of `initState()`.

There are other ways of achieving this but this is the simplest in order for you to understand what is happening here.

Answer (score 0):

Create variable breaks the context chain, doesnt update the ui properly. Instead of create variable, you can create method that will be called inside build method. I am referring

```dart
  Map<String, Map<String, List<Widget>>> data() => {
        "Animation and motion widgets": {
```

And replace the use case `data` with `data()`.